# DDWRT: Is it possible to define the same ip for two different Mac-Addresses?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dd-wrt

Is it Possible to configure ddwrt in such a way, that the dhcp server leases the same static ip (in my case 192.168.2.1) and hostnames for two different mac-adresses?

I have ethernet and wifi in my Notebook and dont want the ip to change in my lan when I undock it, so that my Laptop "ktp" on x.1 is always ktp on x.1 wether I am connected by ethernet or wifi.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too experienced with DD-WRT and networking but you might be able to the assign static ip addresse(192.168.2.1) to the mac address of your wireless card and your ethernet card.  Go to the services tab, then click services again. Under DHCP server add the ip to both mac addresses. Here a link about it: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_DHCP#Configuration

Comment: BTW, if your computer is using Windows, it may be very unhappy with such a setup (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Neither adaptor will work properly and is the definition of an IP conflict.

You *can* set both of your interfaces statically on your local machine to have the same IP address (Windows should warn you but let you do it) if you want to try it out without using DHCP on the DDWRT. I'd suggest you give them an address outside of/adjust your DHCP scope in case you get a third device trying to use the address.

Depending on why you want to do this (for instance if you are accessing a service on your laptop), you may want to look at [DNSMasq.](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_Local_Network)

Comment: at no time both adapters will be activated at the same time. If I connect an Ethernet-Cable, Wifi switches off and vice versa. So it would be a clear state.